# How to modify the ternary diagrams with ggtern

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, ternary, ggtern

How to modify the ternary diagrams with ggtern

I used the following code to plot the ternary diagrams, and want to make some changes:

1. modify the tick labels of x, y, z to probability number (0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1.0)
2. remove the side arrows and corresponding text of x, y, z.
3. remove the second legend (gray/white)
4. replace the text in the first legend with "high" and "low"

> ```
> library(ggtern)
> set.seed(1)
> plot <- ggtern(data = data.frame(x = runif(100),
>                                  y = runif(100),
>                                  z = runif(100)),
>                aes(x, y, z))
>
> plot + stat_density_tern(geom = 'polygon',
>                          n         = 400,
>                          aes(fill  = ..level..,
>                              alpha = ..level..)) +
>   geom_point() +
>   theme_rgbg() +
>   theme(legend.justification=c(0,1), legend.position=c(0,1)) +
>   #theme_gridsontop() + 
>   labs(title = "Example Density/Contour Plot")    +
>   scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue",high = "red")  +
>   # scale_color_gradient(low="yellow",high="red") + 
>   guides(fill = guide_colorbar(order=1),color="none")
> ```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following modifications:

1. The tick labels are controlled by the parameter `labels =`  in each of the three continuous scales used in `ggtern`. These are `scale_L_continuous` for the left-sided edge, `scale_R_continuous` for the right edge, and `scale_T_continuous` for the bottom edge. Set the breaks to `c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1)` (or more succinctly with `0:5 / 5`), and set `labels` to the same values.
2. You can remove the arrows by adding `theme_noarrows()` to your plot.
3. Remove the alpha legend (the grey and white one) using `guides(alpha = guide_none())`
4. You can change the labels of the fill legend (the blue - red one) by passing `labels` as an argument to `scale_fill_gradient`. Since there are 5 breaks (1:5), we pass five labels: `c("low", "", "", "", "high")`

Here's a full reprex. If you cut and paste exactly this code in a fresh R session you should get exactly the same plot:

```r
library(ggtern)
set.seed(1)

ggtern(data = data.frame(x = runif(100), y = runif(100), z = runif(100)),
       mapping = aes(x, y, z = z)) +
  stat_density_tern(geom = 'polygon', n = 400,
                    aes(fill  = ..level.., alpha = ..level..)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red", name = "", breaks = 1:5, 
                      labels = c("low", "", "", "", "high"))  +
  scale_L_continuous(breaks = 0:5 / 5, labels = 0:5/ 5) +
  scale_R_continuous(breaks = 0:5 / 5, labels = 0:5/ 5) +
  scale_T_continuous(breaks = 0:5 / 5, labels = 0:5/ 5) +
  labs(title = "Example Density/Contour Plot") +
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(order = 1), alpha = guide_none()) +
  theme_rgbg() +
  theme_noarrows() +
  theme(legend.justification = c(0, 1), 
        legend.position      = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>